# what does the dollar sign mean in the substitution line of bash command "rename"

Tags: bash, rename, dollar-sign

I was reading about rename and came across this example to change the file extension from htm to html:

```
rename -v 's/\.htm$/\.html/' *.htm
```

and it said: The `$` means the end of the string. `\.htm$` means that it will match `.htm` but not `.html`.

I was a bit confused by the use of `$` here. Since we already specified `*.htm` at the end of command line, `rename` would only select out the htm files (instead of html). So why was it necessary to use the `$` still? In another words, what's wrong with no using `$`?

Comment: I'd have to test this to confirm but presumably without the anchoring `$` that would find the *first* occurrence of `.htm` in the file name and not the extension (i.e. So `foo.htm.htm` for example would become `foo.html.htm` instead of `foo.htm.html`).

Comment: Because it is a regular expression. Look it up; expect to spend all weekend if you want to learn it properly at once.

Comment: The original `rename` command on Unix systems did not allow regular expressions, but many distributions have replaced it over the past few years with Larry Wall's `rename` Perl script.  If you're lucky, your system might have the original `rename` command available as `rename.ul`.  Then you won't have to deal with regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Anchor `$` matches the end of the source file name and it is still required in your regex and dot should also be escaped otherwise `abc.htm.htm` will be renamed to `abc.html.htm` instead of `abc.htm.html`.

Correct command is:

```
rename -v 's/\.htm$/.html/' *.htm
```

Comment: Now it might look same but initially question had `rename -v 's/.htm$/.html/' *.htm` In any case my point was why `$` will still be needed even when filename pattern is `*.htm`